# Using numpy, what is a good way to index into a matrix using another matrix whose entry values are column numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, matrix-indexing

Suppose I want to indepedently re-order each row of a matrix. Here is an example of that using `np.argsort()`:

```
>>> A
array([[88, 44, 77, 33, 77],
       [33, 55, 66, 88,  0],
       [88,  0,  0, 55, 88],
       [ 0, 22, 44, 88, 33],
       [33, 33, 77, 66, 66]])

>>> ind = np.argsort(A); ind
array([[3, 1, 2, 4, 0],
       [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 4, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 4, 2]])

>>> np.array([A[i][ind[i]] for i in range(ind.shape[0])])
array([[33, 44, 77, 77, 88],
       [ 0, 33, 55, 66, 88],
       [ 0,  0, 55, 88, 88],
       [ 0, 22, 33, 44, 88],
       [33, 33, 66, 66, 77]])
```

The last expression above (the one that uses `range()`) is one solution to my problem. My question is: Is there a better way to do this?

The inputs are two matrices like `A` and `ind`, both 2-dimensional and of the same size. The matrix `A` can have any values, and the values of `ind` are interepreted to be column indexes within `A`. The output is a new matrix the same size as `ind` whose values are from `A` as per the above expression: `np.array([A[i][ind[i]] for i in range(ind.shape[0])])`.

Each row of `ind` corresponds to the same row in `A`. Entry `B[i,j]` of the output comes from entry `A[i, ind[i, j]]` of the input.

Note that `ind` may have fewer columns than `A`, and I would like to support that case.

I'm asking because my solution (the given expression) is essentially using a for loop, and maybe numpy can do this more quickly using some internal loop. For my application, speed is important, so it would be nice if I can be time-efficient.

Comment: Replace the iteration with a `np.arange(5)` row index.  That may need some transposes.  Or `np.take_along_axis(A, np.argsort(A),1)`  - read its docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.take_along_axis`was added (recently) to facilitate this kind of indexing.  I believe its docs mention its use with`argsort`:

```
In [113]: A=np.array([[88, 44, 77, 33, 77],
     ...:        [33, 55, 66, 88,  0],
     ...:        [88,  0,  0, 55, 88],
     ...:        [ 0, 22, 44, 88, 33],
     ...:        [33, 33, 77, 66, 66]])
     ...: 
     ...: ind=np.array([[3, 1, 2, 4, 0],
     ...:        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
     ...:        [1, 2, 3, 0, 4],
     ...:        [0, 1, 4, 2, 3],
     ...:        [0, 1, 3, 4, 2]])

In [114]: np.take_along_axis(A, np.argsort(A),1)
Out[114]: 
array([[33, 44, 77, 77, 88],
       [ 0, 33, 55, 66, 88],
       [ 0,  0, 55, 88, 88],
       [ 0, 22, 33, 44, 88],
       [33, 33, 66, 66, 77]])
```

I can do the same with advanced indexing, replacing the `range` iteration with `np.arange`.

```
In [119]: A[np.arange(5),ind.T].T
Out[119]: 
array([[33, 44, 77, 77, 88],
       [ 0, 33, 55, 66, 88],
       [ 0,  0, 55, 88, 88],
       [ 0, 22, 33, 44, 88],
       [33, 33, 66, 66, 77]]
```

I had to add a couple of transpose the get the desired output and layout.  I haven't taken time to figure out just why those are needed.

Applying the argsort to axis 0 can be done with these two:

```
In [123]: A[ind,np.arange(5)]
Out[123]: 
array([[ 0, 55,  0, 66, 77],
       [33, 44, 66, 55, 33],
       [33,  0, 44, 33, 66],
       [88, 55, 77, 55, 33],
       [88, 55, 44, 66, 88]])

In [124]: np.take_along_axis(A, np.argsort(A),0)
Out[124]: 
array([[ 0, 55,  0, 66, 77],
       [33, 44, 66, 55, 33],
       [33,  0, 44, 33, 66],
       [88, 55, 77, 55, 33],
       [88, 55, 44, 66, 88]])
```